# What's the easiest way to count the number of ocurrences of a string in another?

Tags: r

This is what I know I can do i.e. I intend to get the number of occurrences of line break in that string:

```
> res <- grep("\n","why \n is this not \n easier?")
> str(res)
  int 1
> res
[1] 1
>
```

What I'd like to do is to get the actual 2 instead of 1. Is there another way preferably without using third party packages (need to keep my dependency footprint on check).

UPDATE: Using MrFlick solution as inspiration I ended up doing:

```
countOccurrences <- function(pattern, x) {
    return(ifelse(grepl(pattern, x), sapply(gregexpr(pattern, x), length), 0))
}

> countOccurrences("\n", "why \n is this not \n easier?")
[1] 2
> countOccurrences("\n", "why is this not easier?")
[1] 0
> countOccurrences("\n", "why \n is \n this \n not \n easier? \n")
[1] 5
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
test <- c("why \n is this not \n easier?", "none","just\none","\n\n")
res <- gregexpr("\n",test)
sapply(res, function(x) sum(x>=0))
# [1] 2 0 1 2
```

Here we use `gregexpr` because `grep` will only match the first occurrence. Additionally we apply we apply a function to count the number of matched positions (ignoring -1 for no match)

Comment: You could probably avoid the loop by doing something like `length(unlist(res))` or maybe `length(regmatches(x, res)[[1]])`

Comment: The current implementation would work with a vector of strings in which you want to match a particular expression. If you unlist the result, you can only pass one string at a time.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work, if there is no match it will still return a count of 1, which is wrong. The problem is that the vector will still have length 1 but with value -1 meaning no match :/

Comment: But this doesn't give the proper count, it simply sums the positions.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Did you try it? That's not what it's doing. Its summing an indicator, not the positions.

Comment: `fixed = TRUE` in `gregexpr` would probably speed it up a little bit

Answer (score 3):

I know you mention you don't want to use packages, but package `stringi` is quite efficient.

```
library(stringi)
stri_count("why \n is this not \n easier?", fixed = "\n")
# [1] 2
```

If the string contains no matches, `stri_count` will return zero

```
stri_count("why is this not easier?", fixed = "\n")
# [1] 0
```